# Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When I persist a `WorkAction` I need to store the FK Id for `WorkflowInstance`

```
WorkAction wa = new WorkAction();
wa.setWorkflowInstance(wfi);
waDao.persist(wa);
```

However in the table for `WorkAction` the fk column, `workflow_instance_id` winds up being null.

Turns out in the Entity for `WorkAction` I had mapped `WorkflowInstance` using `, insertable = false, updatable = false` like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;
```

When I removed it, I got the `Repeated column in mapping for entity: WorkAction column: workflow_instance_id`  But in the `WorkAction` entity I didn't see `workflow_instance_id` mapped again , i.e. I did not have `private Long workflow_instance_id;`

But then I noticed in my `WorkAction` entity, I had mapped a `WorkflowInstancePlayer` using a formula which referenced `workflow_instamce_id`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({ @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT a.role_class_id FROM WF_WORK_ACTION_CLASS a WHERE a.work_action_class_id = work_action_class_id)", referencedColumnName = "role_class_id")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)) })
private WorkflowInstancePlayer player;
```

Even after adding `insertable=false, updatable=false` to that mapping I still have the issue.  When I comment out the `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` I can remove the `insertable=false, updatable=false` on the `WorkflowInstance` and the workflow_instance_id is then not null but I then lose my `WorkflowInstancePlayer`

How do I get around this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not adding private Long workflow_instance_id to WorkAction class and use it for persisting?

Comment: Yes, because that would also produce the Repeated column in mapping for entity error.

Comment: It would not if you add insertable=false, updatable=false to your joined properties.

Comment: When I simple add  private Long workflow_instance_id; to Class WorkAction, right above the WorkflowInstance @manyToOne mapping, it won't compile, repeated column.

Comment: if I do   @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) private Long workflow_instance_id; it compiles but I'd image when I wa.setWorkflow_instance_id(wfi.getWorkflow_instance_id()); I'd image the persist will still produce null for the fk.  I'll test right now. But where am I supposed to add insertable=false, updatable=false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insertable = false, updatable = false` in your `@JoinColumn` annotations.

```
public class WorkAction {

   @Column(name="workflow_instance_id")
   private Long workflow_instance_id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
       @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT a.role_class_id FROM WF_WORK_ACTION_CLASS a WHERE a.work_action_class_id = work_action_class_id)", referencedColumnName = "role_class_id")),
       @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)) })
   private WorkflowInstancePlayer player;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I reproduced the same case as you did. I think this is some kind of bug because `isUpdatable` and `isInsertable` returns true.

```
protected void checkColumnDuplication(Set distinctColumns, Iterator columns) 
throws MappingException {
    while ( columns.hasNext() ) {
        Selectable columnOrFormula = (Selectable) columns.next();
        if ( !columnOrFormula.isFormula() ) {
            Column col = (Column) columnOrFormula;
            if ( !distinctColumns.add( col.getName() ) ) {
                throw new MappingException( 
                        "Repeated column in mapping for entity: " +
                        getEntityName() +
                        " column: " +
                        col.getName() + 
                        " (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\")"
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void checkPropertyColumnDuplication(Set distinctColumns, Iterator properties) 
throws MappingException {
    while ( properties.hasNext() ) {
        Property prop = (Property) properties.next();
        if ( prop.getValue() instanceof Component ) { //TODO: remove use of instanceof!
            Component component = (Component) prop.getValue();
            checkPropertyColumnDuplication( distinctColumns, component.getPropertyIterator() );
        }
        else {
            if ( prop.isUpdateable() || prop.isInsertable() ) {
                checkColumnDuplication( distinctColumns, prop.getColumnIterator() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source code is from `org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass`

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but this produces the repeated column mapping issue.  Technically, this is really no different than what I have been trying when I did not have insertable = false, updatable = false  on the JoinColumn for WorkflowInstance.  Something is fishy with the crazy JoinColumnsOrFormulas because I don't have this issue with other "normal" entities

Comment: I almost have same class structure but can't check right now. I will post tomorrow again if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: so what does your update mean? Am I screwed?  So Hibernate is ignoring the insertable = false, updatable = false on the JoinColumnOrFormula??

Comment: insertable = false, updatable = false on JoinColumnOrFormula is somehow true everytime but not for JoinColumn alone.

Comment: I guess it's a bug. What version are you using. me hibernate-core: 4.3.8.Final.  I have a bunch other hibernate Dependencies listed in my POM.xml which varying version numbers. I wonder if I am using the latest and greatest and whether cleaning up my dependencies would get me a version of hibernate which works with @JoinColumnOrFormula

Answer (score 0):

**Work Around**

The only way to get this Entity to compile with a column name (workflow_instance_id) in two mappings, one being a standard @JoinColumn and the other @JoinColumn within a @JoinColumnOrFormula, and be able to persist this entity with the workflow_instance_id field populated was to keep insertable = false, updatable = false on my WorkflowInstance mapping without the formula

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;
```

do a normal entity manager persist on the entity

```
WorkAction wa = new WorkAction();
//wa.setWorkflowInstance(wfi); is ignored
wa.set other stuff;
waDao.persist(wa);
```

then do a NativeQueryUpdate to populate the workflow_instance_id column.

```
waDao.updateWfi(wa.getWfi_work_item_action_id(), wfi.getWorkflow_instance_id());


public void updateWfi(Long wfi_work_item_action_id, Long workflow_instance_id) {
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE table_name SET workflow_instance_id = :workflow_instance_id WHERE wfi_work_item_action_id = :wfi_work_item_action_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns with insertable=false and updatable=false, has to be specified first then JoinFormula.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)),
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT a.role_class_id FROM WF_WORK_ACTION_CLASS a WHERE a.work_action_class_id = work_action_class_id)", referencedColumnName = "role_class_id"))
    })
private WorkflowInstancePlayer player;
```

I was also facing similar issue, now the error is gone.