# Problem with inserting entity object in unidirectional One to Many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, each one pointing to one single table in an Oracle Database. The entities belong to an Spring/Maven/JPA/Hibernate web application that works under Weblogic.

The SQL definition for each table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "SUCVIRDASHBOARD"."NEON01_CAMPANIAS" ( 
    "NEON01_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_ID_NEON" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_TITULO" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_ID_IMAGEN" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_TERMINO_CONDICIONES" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "NEON01_URL_ACCION" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "NEON01_ACTIVADO" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_FECHA_MODIFICACION" DATE, 
     CONSTRAINT "NEON01_CAMPANIAS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NEON01_ID")
   );

CREATE TABLE "SUCVIRDASHBOARD"."NEON02_CAMPANIA_CLIENTE" (
    "NEON02_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON02_RUT" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON02_PCS" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON01_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON02_FECHA_CARGA" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON02_FECHA_DESPLIEGUE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NEON02_FECHA_FINALIZACION" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "NEON02_CAMPANIA_CLIENTE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NEON02_ID")
);
```

Although there is no foreign key, a NEON01_CAMPANIAS can be associated to one or many NEON02_CAMPANIA_CLIENTE using the latter table's id (this is an **unidirectional** relationship). Based on this, Using JPA, I defined the entity for each table as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NEON01_CAMPANIAS")
public class NeonCampana {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="NEON01_ID")
    private Long id;
    /* More attributes, getters and setters */
}

@Entity
@Table(name="NEON02_CAMPANIA_CLIENTE")
public class NeonClienteCampana {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="NEON02_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="NEON01_ID")
    private List<NeonCampana> campanias;
    /* More attributes, getters and setters */
}
```

I can select and insert in NEON01_CAMPANIAS without problems, using, respectively, the `createCriteria` and `save` methods of the Hibernate's `Session` interface.
But when I want to save an `NeonClienteCampana` object with associated `NeonCampana` objects in the `campanias` `List` using the following code:

```
NeonClienteCampana cliente = new NeonClienteCampana();
cliente.setFechaCarga(hoy);
cliente.setFechaDespliegue(hoy);
cliente.setFechaFinalizacion(hoy);
cliente.setRut(item.getRut().longValue());
cliente.setPcs(item.getPcs());
List<NeonCampana> clienteCampanas = new ArrayList<>();
clienteCampanas.add(campanaDash);
cliente.setCampanias(clienteCampanas);
neonClienteService.guardar(cliente);
```

I got the following error message:

`ERROR: ORA-01400: Cannot insert null in ("SUCVIRDASHBOARD"."NEON02_CAMPANIA_CLIENTE"."NEON01_ID")`

I tried the following solution explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3725194/2988946

However, when i deploy the application, I get the following exception:`org.hibernate.MappingException:Repeated column in mapping for entity: cl.clarochile.sucvirdashboard.dao.models.NeonCampana column: NEON01_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Afterwards, I tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34025677/2988946, but I got the same exception

Given the circunstance, how can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That happens, because you have two attributes pointing to the same column. For example, when you map your `@OneToMany` as you entity object, and then you add another long object as a key mapping. In that case, hibernate is confused and asking you to make one of those attributes immutable, so it can handle updates only from one side. You have to either remove it or make your `@Column` to be immutable this way:

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
```